# redirectTo in angular2 for child routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to use `redirectTo` in the case of child routing with a parameter in angular2. my routing structure like this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo : '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'xyz/:id', component: XYZ },
    {
        path: 'abc/:id', component: ABC,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo : 'def', pathMatch: 'prefix' },
          { path: 'def/:id', component: DEF }
        ]
    }
]
```

But it's not working

also, what is `pathMatch` in routing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for your sample code, if paths 'abs/:id' and 'def/:id' use the same parameter (:id), the solution that I use was to forget the parameter in child route configuration and in its component get from its parent route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: ':id',
    component: SimulatorComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeComponent
        }
    ]
}
```

];

In HomeComponent, then you catch the id from parent route:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    protected id: number;

    constructor(protected route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => this.id = +params['id']);
    }
```

}

Comment: sorry but in my case `id` is not same ;) what to do now ?

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect to `home` (without the slash), since your `redirectTo` value needs to match a given `path`, not an arbitrary url.

For details about the `pathMatch` attribute, see the section in Angular2's [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) docs.

Comment: If you put a slash before a url in `redirectTo` it means it's an absolute redirect url. So it is valid. Correct me if this has changed.

Answer (score 1):

> pathMatch = 'full' results in a route hit when the remaining, unmatched segments of the URL match is the prefix path
>
> pathMatch = 'prefix' tells the router to match the redirect route when the remaining URL **begins** with the redirect route's prefix path.

Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#redirect

So let's take a look at your example:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo : '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'xyz/:id', component: XYZ },
    {
        path: 'abc/:id', component: ABC,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo : 'def', pathMatch: 'prefix' }, //error
          { path: 'def/:id', component: DEF }
        ]
    }
]
```

Error line means that if something like `abc/1 + ''` (which is `abc/1`) is entered, `redirectTo = 'def'` (full path = `'abc/:id/def'`) which doesn't exist.

With `pathMatch = prefix` if you enter anything after `abc/1` it will still try to `redirectTo = 'def'` (e.g `abc/1/longesturl`) because after `abc/1 + ''` this `''` matches any url because every url after `1` will have an empty string in it.

Comment: Exactly well explained answer so whats the solution of the same

Comment: @PardeepJain if you want it to be redirected To `'def'` path then you must create a `'def'` path

Comment: But I don't have path named Def along instead def with parameters. Now what to do ?? Any idea

Comment: @PardeepJain That is why you are getting the error. Either create a `'def'` path or redirect it to something else.

Comment: @PardeepJain where did you created it? Where is it's path in the `appRoutes`?

Comment: resolved the issue using above answer, btw nice exlanation thankuu so much.

Comment: please add bit more explanation if you can about `pathMatch` , i mean when to use `full` or `prefix`

Comment: @PardeepJain Glad you figured it out :) I will add more explanation when I have the time ;) thanks